# Swagger UI not working with spring security and jwt when application deployed to docker

Tags: docker, spring-security, jwt, swagger-ui

So I have spring security configured to my springboot 3 application. Also The application uses JWT token to authenticate the end points. Everything is working fine on local machine. But once I create a docker image and run the application end points are working fine swagger UI is not accessible any more. This is my security configuration:

**application.properies**

```
server.servlet.context-path=/
```

**SecurityConfiguration**

```java
@Configuration
//@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors((cors) -> cors.disable()).csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
//                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz)->authz.requestMatchers("swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "api/v1/auth/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "api/v1/auth/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()).csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
                .sessionManagement((session) -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterAfter(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    /* @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authz->authz.anyRequest().permitAll());
        return http.build();
    }*/

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}
```